# How to add a GUI to a minimal install of CentOS?

Tags: centos

I did a minimal install of CentOS 6.3 and now want to add a GUI. I tried using `yum` to install a GUI, but it is unable to resolve the CentOS repository server  `mirror.centos.org`. I tried to install networking packages but I get `directory not found` for `/etc`.

How can I install and enable Gnome Desktop on CentOS?

Comment: "... I get directory not found for /etc." What?

Comment: I saw this on the original question (before I edited) and also was puzzled. To the OP, can you revert my edit and reword your question so it's more readable?

Comment: Are we talking about a vps or hosting setup here?

Answer (score 3):

try yum groupinstall basic-desktop desktop-platform x11 fonts

But apparently your yum is unable to connect to the yum repository. that is mirror.centos.org.
Do check your network configuration.